# NACK a message in apache nms

Tags: c#, stomp, apache-nms

I'm trying use apache nms stomp for send/receive messages. I can not use Transnational ack mode, because of using hornetq. My consumer scenario:

1. Receive a message
2. Process the message
3. ACK it if process succeed (with message.Acknowledge())
4. NACK it if process failed (????)

All i want is NACK the message if process is failed; so how can i NACK a message in apache nms?

Comment: Need more info.  What does your STOMP provider support in terms of STOMP protocols.  You need at least 1.1 for a NACK message.

Comment: Hornetq-2.3.0.CR2 supports 1.1 and 1.2.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any reason why you can't use transactions with HornetQ.  The only way currently to have the client send a NACK is to use a transaction and Rollback the Transaction on error.  Once you reach the configured Max allowed redeliveries the client will NACK the Message.

In most implementations if your client doesn't ACK a Message and then disconnects the message would be redelivered to another client.  In the case of ActiveMQ you can configure a maximum number of times that the broker would attempt this before it moved the message into a Dead Letter Queue.

As it stands right now the NMS.Stomp implementation doesn't NACK a message when an exception is thrown from the asynchronous message callback however this could be a sensible enhancement, the project does accept contributions so dive in.

Comment: HornetQ user manual: Message acknowledgements are not transactional. The ACK frame can not be part of a transaction
(it will be ignored if its transaction header is set).

Comment: Then Use ActiveMQ or Apollo which is spec compliant.

Comment: If i don't Ack a message, will it remain in the queue? (the message won't be lost?)